# apply substituting for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I´m trying to learn how to use `function` and `apply` instead of for-loops, as it supposedly takes less time. Can anyone give me advise on how to change the following code in order to reduce time spent?

The goal is to make `RF` have the same properties at `Dates` but with the corresponding `Euribor` returns instead of the "dates" in `Dates`. The dates are "serialnumber-dates" in both `Euribor` and `Dates` (class: numeric).

Example Data(output of this code is my similar to my input):

```
Dates=matrix(NA,4,10)
Dates[1,1:8]=seq(3610,3617,1)
Dates[2,1:10]=seq(3613,3622,1)
Dates[3,1:5]=seq(3615,3619,1)
Dates[4,1:7]=seq(3616,3622,1)

Euribor=matrix(0,2,51)
Euribor[1,]=seq(3600,3650,1)
Euribor[2,]=rnorm(51)
```

This solution returns the correct output, but takes very long time with a 4500x4700 matrix.

```
RF = matrix(0,nrow(Dates),ncol(Dates))
for (i in 1:nrow(Dates)){
In=grep(Dates[i,1],Euribor[1,])
end=sum(!is.na(Dates[i,]))
RF[i,1:end]=as.matrix(Euribor[2,In:(In+end-1)])
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You should add a quick example of the data and what you'd like the output to look like.

Comment: Tried to make it more understandable now, @Kristofersen

Comment: you really need to include what the output should look like too.

Comment: And remember, matrices cannot have mixed types. Either all elements are *dates* or all are *numbers*, not both at same time.

Comment: Included code to run now. All elements are of class numeric.

Comment: @HaakonR Sorry, I'm sure this is getting annoying, but it is much preferred to include a small example. If you could include just a 10x10 or a 5x5. That way you can easily show what the input looks like and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Okey, but i´m not sure I understand. I have included example data in the form of to matrices: `Dates` and `Euribor. The output of the first code is my input. The output in the last code is my wanted output. Do you want the input and output shown as matrices in the question, @Kristofersen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dates=matrix(NA,4,10)
Dates[1,1:8]=seq(3610,3617,1)
Dates[2,1:10]=seq(3613,3622,1)
Dates[3,1:5]=seq(3615,3619,1)
Dates[4,1:7]=seq(3616,3622,1)

Euribor=matrix(0,2,51)
Euribor[1,]=seq(3600,3650,1)
Euribor[2,]=rnorm(51)

RF = matrix(0,nrow(Dates),ncol(Dates))
for (i in 1:nrow(Dates)){
  In=grep(Dates[i,1],Euribor[1,])
  end=sum(!is.na(Dates[i,]))
  RF[i,1:end]=as.matrix(Euribor[2,In:(In+end-1)])
}

RF2 = matrix(Euribor[2,match(c(Dates), Euribor[1,])], nrow = nrow(Dates), ncol = ncol(Dates))
```

So, RF2 is the fast way to do this and should be the same as RF.

```
    > RF
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]
[1,] -0.0819133 -0.08336513  0.6926775  1.0500598 -0.5244457  1.1804117  1.7349849 1.3002456  0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,]  1.0500598 -0.52444574  1.1804117  1.7349849  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350 0.9480801 -0.7692101 0.3189216
[3,]  1.1804117  1.73498487  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,]  1.7349849  1.30024557 -0.7438148 -1.2804350  0.9480801 -0.7692101  0.3189216 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
> RF2
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]
[1,] -0.0819133 -0.08336513  0.6926775  1.0500598 -0.5244457  1.1804117  1.7349849 1.3002456         NA        NA
[2,]  1.0500598 -0.52444574  1.1804117  1.7349849  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350 0.9480801 -0.7692101 0.3189216
[3,]  1.1804117  1.73498487  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA
[4,]  1.7349849  1.30024557 -0.7438148 -1.2804350  0.9480801 -0.7692101  0.3189216        NA         NA        NA
```

We can replace the NAs with 0s like this

```
RF2[is.na(RF2)] = 0
> RF2
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]     [,10]
[1,] -0.0819133 -0.08336513  0.6926775  1.0500598 -0.5244457  1.1804117  1.7349849 1.3002456  0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,]  1.0500598 -0.52444574  1.1804117  1.7349849  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350 0.9480801 -0.7692101 0.3189216
[3,]  1.1804117  1.73498487  1.3002456 -0.7438148 -1.2804350  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
[4,]  1.7349849  1.30024557 -0.7438148 -1.2804350  0.9480801 -0.7692101  0.3189216 0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Edit:
I figured I should probably explain how this works. Essentially all we need is the index in Euribor where the Date values are. I figured the easiest way to do this was to collapse Date into a vector and then match the locations of the date values back into Euribor and take the values in col 2 on the matches.

Collapsing Date into a vector goes by column and so does matrix by default so it constructs it back into the form we're looking for.

Finally, we can just swap out all the NAs at the end, and that part is pretty easy.

Since we've removed the need for the for loop this will be much faster. I'm not sure of how we could use an apply function here. There probably is a way but it's not needed to speed it up.

Comment: @HaakonR happy to help :)